# Change from Remote to Embedded Signing

Tags: docusignapi

I have a remote envelope that's out for signature. I know how to create an embedded envelope, but I'm not sure how I can change a remote envelope to an embedded envelope.

Any help?

Comment: No help at all? Even from docusign developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Embedding vs. Remote does not apply to the "envelope" per say but rather it applies to your recipients.

For instance, you can have an envelope with 2 recipients where the first has been added as a Remote recipient (and thus will receive an email to initiate the signing) and the second has been added as an Embedded recipient meaning you will handle creating the signing URL and navigating them there, etc.

Therefore, if you added someone as Remote and want to change them to Embedded (or vice-versa) you can do a Correction of that envelope.  Take a look at the following REST API call:

[Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Information](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20or%20Correct%20and%20Resend%20Recipient%20Information.htm)

Note that to configure the recipient as embedded you will need to set their `clientUserId` property to a non-null value.

---

**UPDATE**

---

Note: If the system does not let you add the `clientUserId` property of a recipient then you might have to

1. Delete the recipient from the envelope
2. Add them back in with the clientUserId assigned

To delete the recipient from the envelope you can make this call:

[Delete Recipient](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Delete%20Recipients%20from%20an%20Envelope.htm)

Then to add them back in with the new info:

[Add Recipient](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Add%20Recipients%20to%20an%20Envelope.htm)

Comment: This is from the link you gave: "Once an envelope has been sent, you can only edit: email, userName, signerName, routingOrder, faxNumber, and deliveryMethod." I also tried to update the clientUserId, and it won't update. I can see the correction completed message, so I know it was submitted.

Comment: Can this be because I'm using xml? I'm using .../envelopes/-ENVELOPE_ID- and I'm using the same xml structure I use to create an envelope. <envelope....><receipients><signers><signer>.....</envelope>

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer please have a look and test.  You'll probably need to delete the recipient (remove them from the envelope) then add them back (instead of just modify them).

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing. I was afraid the signer would get notified but he doesn't. Thanks!